# how to use ffmpeg with vidstab and filter_complex

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am currently trying to make the best of some bad quality smartphone recordings.
Since these are round about 30 video files that are very similar in audio and video, I figured I could use ffmpeg for this batch work.

I experimented with vidstab and found very pleasant results with using it in two pass mode:
(as also found in [ffmpeg: combining/ordering vidstab and crop filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598047/ffmpeg-combining-ordering-vidstab-and-crop-filters))

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf
>   vidstabdetect=stepsize=32:shakiness=10:accuracy=10:result=result.trf
>   -f null -

and after that went with

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=7:input=result.trf
>   newfile.mp4

The main goal is also fading video and audio in and out for a fix amount of time plus adding image improvement with eq filter.
I want to use (from there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128754/how-do-i-add-a-1-second-fade-out-effect-to-the-end-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time='$offset'[v];[0:a]afade=type=in:duration=1,afade=type=out:duration=1:start_time='$offset'[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" fade/"$f"
```

All commands itself work fine.

The question is: how can I combine -vf and -filter_complex for my desired purpose?
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Of course for a two-pass filter you need at least two passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the preliminary pass to get stabilization info:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[0:v]vidstabdetect=stepsize=32:shakiness=10:accuracy=10:result=result.trf" -an -f null -
```

- `-an` was added to ignore audio. You don't need to decode any audio, so it will process slightly faster.

Now run the second command incorporating vidstabtransform:

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter_complex "[0:v]vidstabtransform=smoothing=7:input=result.trf,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time='$offset'[v];[0:a]afade=type=in:duration=1,afade=type=out:duration=1:start_time='$offset'[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" fade/"$f"
```

Comment: it's as easy as that! Thanks a lot for your help:)